# How subprocess.popen is used

Tags: python, subprocess

Why do I get an error when I run subprocess.popen?

I load a command with arguments in a variable, I do a split and pass the result to subprocess.Popen. **It returns an error**.

*Thank you all very much for your collaboration*

The complete code is as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import subprocess
import shlex


def main():
    try:
            data = "ls -al"
            args = shlex.split(data)
            comando = subprocess.Popen(args, shell=True,stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.PIPE)

            if comando.stderr.read() != "":
                print("[-] Error")
            else:
                print(comando.stdout.read())
    except Exception as e:
        print (e)

if __name__ == '__main__' :
    try:
        main()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        exit()
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: What is the error? Please paste the error code.

Comment: The following error appears: "[-] Error", as a result of executing the following branch if "if command.stderr.read ()! =" ":"

Comment: Perhaps you should have printed the result of `comando.stderr.read()`, rather than throwing away the only clue as to what went wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [communicate](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate)

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import subprocess
import shlex


def main():
    try:
            data = "ls -al"
            args = shlex.split(data)
            comando = subprocess.Popen(args, shell=True,stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
            comando_stdout, comando_stderr = comando.communicate()
            if comando_stderr:
                print("[-] Error")
            else:
                print(comando_stdout)
    except Exception as e:
        print (e)

if __name__ == '__main__' :
    try:
        main()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        exit()
```